# FileSystemWatcher in Java - Deleting a directory being watched

Tags: java, directory, filesystemwatcher

I have implemented a file system watcher. Whenever I try to delete watched directory, it generates `ENTRY_MODIFY` events for all the files or sub directories inside that directory. Is there any way to find that there was delete command for the watched directory? I do not want to watch the parent directory because in this way all the other files and folders will also be watched for changes.

Comment: Without some code we're all guessing. Please show what you have done, edited down to a minimal [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: public void registerWithWatchService(String path) {dirpath = path;
  Path dir = Paths.get(path);try {
   WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE,ENTRY_MODIFY);}
               catch (IOException x) {}
public void processEvents() {
 while (true) {
 WatchKey key; try {
    key = watcher.take();
   } catch (InterruptedException x) {
    return;
   }
for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) { WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
Path filename = ev.context();
Path dir = (Path)key.watchable();    Path }}

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a library like Apache Commons VFS or [`org.apache.commons.io.monitor`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/monitor/package-summary.html) that provides functions like this. In any case, I think you have to monitor the parent directory of the directory you are interested in.

Here is a small (not tested!) example:

```
File directory = new File("c:/your/parent/dir"));
FileAlterationObserver observer = new FileAlterationObserver(directory);
observer.addListener(new FileAlterationListener() {

    // here you have to implement some methods, this is the pertinent one for you: 
    public void onDirectoryDelete(File directory) {
        // do your processing here
    }
});

FileAlterationMonitor monitor = new FileAlterationMonitor(interval);
monitor.addObserver(observer);
monitor.start();
```